# Separation of Variables for second order PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I have a PDE that I have attempted to solve using the method of 'separation of variables'

$$u_t = (1+2t)u_{xx} \,\,\,\, 0 \leq x < \pi, t \geq 0 $$

With initial and boundary conditions:

$$u(0,t) = 0 $$

$$u(\pi, t) = \pi $$

$$ u(x,0) = 0$$

Using separation of variables, we have

$$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$$

$$\frac{T'}{(1+2t)T} = \lambda = \frac{X''}{X}$$

This yields,

$$T = Ae^{\lambda(t + t^2)} $$
$$X = B\sinh(\omega x)$$

Where $\lambda =  \omega^2 > 0$, given that $X(\pi) = \pi$, we have

$$B= \frac{\pi}{\sinh(\omega \pi)} $$

So our final solution is

$$u(x,t) = Ae^{\lambda(t + t^2)}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\omega \pi)}\sinh(\omega x)\right)$$

However, I cannot find a function for A that would satisfy the initial and boundary conditions. Can someone tell me where I have made a mistake. Do I have to do something to deal with the (1 + 2t) coefficient or have I just made a mistake in implementing the method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be a wonderful world if it was, but alas it is not. $X(\pi)$ is a non-zero demon.

Comment: Are you sure? There is absolutely no way to solve it analytically?

Comment: Notice that you have additional solutions to the equation $X''-\lambda X=0$. Namely, $X(x)=x$ for $\lambda=0$ and $X(x)=\sin(\omega x)$ for $\lambda=-\omega^2$ negative such that $\sin(\omega \pi)=\pi$. You can try to use these additional solutions to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to account for the possibility that $\lambda=0$. Then you have
$$ T'=X''=0, $$
so you can have $Bx+C$ as another solution. Setting $x=0$ implies that $C=0$, and $x=\pi$ gives $C=1$, but you have to deal with the initial condition separately. Define $U=u-x$, then $U$ satisfies
$$ U_t=(1+2t)U_{xx}, $$
but with different BCs:
$$ U(0,t)=0, \quad U(\pi,t) = 0, \quad U(x,0)=-x. $$
But you should recognise this as a problem you can solve using separation of variables and Fourier series: separate variables $U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then
$$ T'=\lambda(1+2t)T, \quad X''=\lambda X, $$
so $T$ is as you have it, and the boundary conditions imply that $\lambda<0$, so $X=\sin{nx}$, for $n\in \{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$. Now you have to solve for the initial condition with
$$ -x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin{nx} $$
for $a_n$ in the usual way. You can then verify that
$$ u(x,t) = x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n e^{-n(t+t^2)}\sin{nx} $$
solves the original problem.

**Remark:** the simpler way to do this is to include $\lambda=0$ as another Fourier mode with no period, but this way of splitting into problems that are easier to solve is very useful.

Comment: But the condition that $u(x,0) = 0$ is then not satisfied, as $u(x,0) = x + \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n\sin(nx)$, which is non-zero for non-zero $x$

Comment: apologies, didnt factor in that $-x = \sum^{\infty} a_n \sin(nx)$. Thanks for your help, was a subtle transformation i didn't spot

Comment: Can i ask why you didn't use a constant of integration when calculating T?

Comment: Since in that case ($\lambda=0$) $T$ is just a constant, multiplying $X$ by it doesn't do anything to the form of the equation, so you can essentially forget about it.

Comment: Would it then be appropriate to say that this is a fourier sine series and $$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n\sin(nx) \sin(nx) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 -x \sin(nx) = \frac{-2}{n} $$

Comment: That's the idea, although I don't think your calculation's quite right.

Comment: yes, i think it should be $\frac{(-1)^n 2}{n}$

Comment: Looks more plausible: you expect the derivative to exist at $0$, but not at $\pi$, after all.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a diffusion equation.
So I get another solution

$
u (t,x) =K \frac{{{e}^{-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{2\, \left( 2\, t+1\right) }}}}{\sqrt{2\,t+1}} - K
$

but I also have a problem with the boundary conditions.